# Anchor link in template breaks when page has URL parameters

Tags: templates, url

I've got a problem with my Joomla site.

I've got an anchor link in my template -- really simple, like this: `<a href='#top'>Go to top</a>`.

This works great for most pages on the site.

But on some pages (eg search), we allow URL arguments. On those pages, Joomla is rewriting the anchor link to remove the URL arguments. This means it no longer points to the current page, so it doesn't work as simply "go to top", it reloads the page without any parameters. This is not what I want.

All I want is a plain simple html anchor link. I don't want Joomla to be clever and rewrite the URL; it doesn't need rewriting.

Is there any way to stop Joomla from rewriting this URL?

Comment: For the record, I've created an issue in Joomla's issue tracker for this: https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/9010

Comment: I commented on the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another idea would be to provide the right URL for the anchor. In your template you can do something like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo JUri::getInstance(); ?>#top">Go to top</a>
```

This will add the full URL of your current site in front of the "#top"

Comment: Thanks. This solved the problem. Seems like more of a work-around than a fix, but it's enough to get me back on track. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

1. Sourcerer http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer
2. it enables you to wrap code in {source}Go to top{/source} - perhaps this will stop the rewrite

Comment: Looks like it might do the trick, but seems like it would be overkill to have to use a plugin for this. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood your question and thought it was in a module in the template rather than "In" the template index.php file - so my answer won't work.